# Printing on hardened windows clients

Tags: windows, active-directory, group-policy, hardening

I have inherited hardened clients with a lot of policies applied to them. There is an application running on this clients, that should show the windows printing dialog, but it does not pop up.[image: Expected printing dialog]

There are no policies regarding printers configured, and I have no idea which policies stop this dialog from appearing. How can I find out which one it is? Maybe someone have an idea, which policies to test.

If I disable all policies one by one, it will take forever to test. Hopefully, somebody has an idea which one it might be.

Comment: Use `rsop.msc` to see exactly what settings are applied to the workstation and from what policies.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I will definitely check that. But I need to find out which setting blocks this dialogue, and there are well over a hundred policies in place. I have no idea how to even narrow it down.

Comment: Here is my suggestion: Download Procmon, close your application, start the Procmon capture, start the app, try to display the print dialog (see that the print dialog doesn't shows up), stop the Procmon capture, then Add the following filter: "Path Contains `Policies` Include" and "Result Is `SUCCESS` Include". Now, review the items shown in the capture, you may find something with a relevant name in it, or post the results here.